xltabular creates unnecessary space
Problem
I have an environment of a table using xltabular (and LuaLaTeX), but it always creates a blank space after the table has ended. I think it does a parskip as if I set it to 0pt the parameter, the result is what I look for.

But obviously I don't want to change the parskip parameter as I want it to 10pt while I'm normally writing. I have tried different things as adding a \vspace{-10pt} at the end of the definition of the new environment but it doesn't work, the same happens if I try to reset the parskip to 0pt only during the table is created.
I have also tried to make a newenvironment of my previous environment adding the vspace, making something like this:
\newenvironment{newtab}[3]
{\begin{tab}{#1}{#2}{#3}}
{\end{tab} \vspace{-10pt}}

And again, didn't work, but now because a big error (didn't even compile pdf). This error ! File ended while scanning use of \TX@get@body. which I have no idea what it means.
MWE
There are some comments of what I tried and didn't work
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, lmargin=2.75cm, rmargin=2.75cm, tmargin=3cm, bmargin=3cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage{array, xcolor, xltabular, colortbl, amssymb, fontawesome5, multirow, tabularray}
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

\newenvironment{tab}[3]{\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}\xltabular{\textwidth}{#2}
    \hline
    \rowcolor{yellow} #3 \\
    \hline
    \endfirsthead
    \multicolumn{#1}{c}{\phantom{\textsubw{\textsubw{\textsubw{k}}}}\hspace{-5.2pt} % this is to make the cell taller
 \color{yellow} \faArrowUp \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowUp \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowUp \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowUp \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowUp} \\
    \hline
    \endhead
    \multicolumn{#1}{c}{\phantom{\textoverw{\textoverw{\textoverw{k}}}}\hspace{-5.2pt} % this is to make the cell taller
 \color{yellow} \faArrowDown \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowDown \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowDown \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowDown \quad\quad\quad\quad\quad \faArrowDown}
    \endfoot
    \hline
    \endlastfoot
}{\endxltabular\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1}%

% \vspace{-10pt}
% \setlength{\parskip}{0pt}

}


\begin{document}

Some text to show the spacing between this and the table.

\begin{tab}{3}{|X|X|X|}{Column 1 & Column 2 & Column 3}
    1 & 1 & 1 \\\hline
    2 & 2 & 2 \\\hline
    3 & 3 & 3
\end{tab}
% \vspace{-10pt} ONLY THIS WORKS, NOT AN ELEGANT SOLUTION
Some text to show the spacing between this and the table.

\end{document}


Yor document example is not compilable. Please test it before publish it here. In preamble you define parskip which value is added to default vertical space before/after table. In preamble you load tabularray package. Why you not use its longtblr instead of xltabular (its kode is shorter)? Does your table has caption?

The example works fine (it's in lualatex), tabularray is not necessary that's my fault. I use xltabular as I can use the X cell and have the longtable break between pages. My table has no caption (or shouldn't have any)

The empty lines in the end part of your tab definition is a end of paragraph and you've setup to add paragraph distance after paragraphs. But also without these empty lines, xltabular would add a paragraph. So for short tabulars inside a paragraph you should use tabularx instead of xltabular.

But I would like to have a general tab environment and not think about if a table is going to break or not, specially if the document has a lot of pages and tables

I test your document with LuaLaTeX (as is in recent MiKTeX bundle) and it doesn't work, there is some problem with tipa package  (can be fault in my installation). longtblr also support long tables (over may pages),  X column type and may more, For your use it not be need to define new environment . For common features of tables instead of new environment you can define \SetTblrInner{...}.

\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt} (or some negative value) should work.

thank you A LOT, it works

You can reduce the space after the longtable with
\setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}


Since in preamble you load tabularray package, I would exploit its features to write your table.
Edit:
Any long tables have prescribed vertical space above and below of table. For example at \longtbltr of tabularray package it is 1.5\bigskipamount. If this space is not what you like to have, packages provide commands by which you can change size of those spaces. For example, at longtblr they are presep and postsep which values should be determined in \SetTblrOuter[longtblr]{ ... }:
\SetTblrOuter[longtblr]{presep =0.75\bigskipamount, % <-- space above table
                        postsep=0.75\bigskipamount} % <-- space below table; 

In the case, when you use parskip package for determining space above paragraphs, those spaces you should consider in defining amount of the postsep as I did in MWE below.
Code, which produce in question showed table, using longtblr can be:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, 
            hmargin=2.75cm, vmargin=3cm]{geometry} % margins
\usepackage[safe]{tipa}
\usepackage{fontawesome5}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\SetTblrOuter[longtblr]{presep =0.75\bigskipamount, % <-- space above table
                        postsep=0pt}                % <-- space below table; 
                                                    %     it is equivalent to \LTpost at longtable
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[66]

\begin{longtblr}[
    entry=none,     % <--- no caption
    label=none,     % <--- no referencing of table
                ]{hlines, vlines,
                   colspec = {*{3}{X}},
                   rowsep=5pt,
                   row{1} ={bg=yellow},
                   rowhead=1,
                   }
Column  1   & Column 2  & Column 3  \\  
        1   & 1         & 1         \\
        2   & 2         & 2         \\
        3   & 3         & 3         \\
\end{longtblr}

\lipsum[11]

\lipsum[66]

\end{document}

Result of compilation is:

